# Old Anime (similar to Pokemon) that involved going to different places (/times?) and capturing monsters in their eggs?

Tags: flint-the-time-detective

I've been trying to find the name of this show for YEARS. I watched it every day when I was young (around 10 years ago now). I'm pretty sure it was on Channel 5 (for all you English people) in the early morning since I would watch it before school.

All I can remember is that there was a group of kids and they'd travel to different places (maybe times too?) and would have to capture some kind of monster (similar to Pokemon/Digimon) that was causing havoc. Each monster I believe was recaptured in an egg (each egg was also unique) and there was usually just one per episode. There may have been some kind of scientist involved with a machine that sent them to these places? But my memories may just be getting confused with Pokemon at that point.
I know it wasn't Monster Rancher as I've had suggested by friends but beyond that I've no clue.

Any ideas? I really loved it and it would be amazing to rediscover it after all these years.

Comment: Are you sure it's not digimon ? [Digimon Data Squad](http://myanimelist.net/anime/859/Digimon_Savers) also recapture bad digimon in egg form.

Comment: Digimon is the first thing that came to my mind as well.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like [**Flint the Time Detective**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2281/Jikuu_Tantei_Genshi-kun)

[image]

> It is the 25th century. The dark lord has 'infected' history with time-devices that could damage history beyond repair. Flint and his father lived in the prehistorics when they got turned into fossiles. They are discovered and Flint ges turned back to his original state. With the help of his father, a boy Tony and a girl Sara he has to travel trough time to bring the time-devices back to the land of time so history will be saved.

In particular there are creatures called [time-shifters](http://flintthetimedetective.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Shifters) that can assume different forms, among which there is an egg-like form ([monster egg](http://flintthetimedetective.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Eggs)).